# ASP.NET MVC ViewManager equivalent

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm looking into ASP.NET MVC, and whether or not to make the switch. One thing that I do a heck of a lot in ASP.NET, is to render HTML on AJAX callbacks and sent back to the client. I use a [generic ViewManager](http://weblogs.asp.net/stefansedich/archive/2008/03/10/a-generic-viewmanager-helper-class.aspx) for rendering User Controls.

I created a sample MVC App from the templates, and was looking for the RenderUserControl method inside a Controller. I found: System.Web.Mvc.Html.RenderPartialExtensions.RenderPartial but that doesn't seem to be what I'm looking for in this context.

Is there an equivalent to the ASP.NET ViewManager in MVC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is return a partial view:

```
public ActionResult IWillCallThisViaAjax()
{
    return PartialView("MyUserControlName");
}
```